# Python C Api transfer a PyObject * into c array

Tags: python, c++, arrays, python-c-api

I used python c api and wish to get an array back from python. I returned a python array from the python side and want to transfer the PyObject* result into a c array so I can use it.

Is there anyway I can do that?

Side questions: In what circumstance trying to return an element in the array like

```
return arr[3]
```

will cause the PyObject_callobject return NULL?

```
return arr
```

does give me something

Comment: When you say you want to transfer the `PyObject *` result into a C array, do you mean a C array of `PyObject *` or do you want to translate those array member objects into a more native C representation as well?

Comment: @KenClement I'd say probably as well. If I'm not mistaken I can use Pystring_fromstring to translate its member seperately. On the side note, when I do type(arr[3]) in python it tells me that it's unicode. Does that make any difference with string?

Comment: You are on the right track about using `Pystring_fromstring` but it does matter what version of Python you are using (2.7 or 3.5).  (Also, I should probably ask if you are using CPython or IronPython or PyPy - I'm guessing from your remarks that its CPython)  The difference between 2.7 and 3.5 will determine whether or not unicode makes a difference with `str`.  In CPython 2.7 `str` generally deals with narrow character data - not unicode.  In 3.5 that distinction has been erased (all strings are unicode).  The AP{I's are not  compatible in this regard.  Which version are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python an "array" is a `list` datatype.  Look at the `PyList_*` functions in the C API.  You can find this reference [here for 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html) and [here for 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/list.html).  The functions of interest are:

`Py_ssize_t PyList_Size(PyObject *list)` to get the number of list members
     and
`PyObject* PyList_GetItem(PyObject *list, Py_ssize_t index)` to get a reference to the member at that index.

A simple use of `malloc` or similar allocator and a `for` loop should do the trick.

Also note that only borrowed references are involved, so no reference count maintenance of these objects via `void Py_INCREF(PyObject *o)` and `void Py_DECREF(PyObject *o)` is necessary.