# How to retrieve data from a returned numpy array in a C program?

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, c-api

I have a main program written in C and would like to use an already written library in Python, so I embedded some C-Python API into my C program.

I have successfully created a PyObject that represents a numpy array, containing float data in C, and sent it as an argument to a function defined inside a Python script, which will be called by the C program via the following command:

```
pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);,
```

where the `pFunc` is the name of the function to be called in the Python script, `pArgs` is a PyObject containing arguments to be passed to the function, and `pValue` is of type PyObject 
which I believe that it will contain the returned result.

The function inside the Python script processes the sent array and then returns a 2-dimensional numpy array of shape `(nrow, ncol)`, containing float data, to my main C program.

How can I retrieve the data inside the returned array, and copy them to a C array?

There is an example in https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding showing how to retrieve a long value by using

`int d = PyLong_AsLong(pValue));`

But, what's about a numpy array? Is there something like PyArray_AsCArray() that can be used?

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628180/passing-a-numpy-array-to-c

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141827/python-c-api-transfer-a-pyobject-into-c-array